# What kind of language construct is the swung dash (tilde, ~)?

Tags: bash, console, posix, home, tilde

The swung dash can be used in place of the home directory. Depending on the current user it has a different value. In this sense it works like a variable.

Yet it is not a variable. I can't do `echo $~` but I can do `echo ~`.

What kind of language construct is it?

Comment: Related: Tilde expansion in the POSIX shell standard: https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01

Comment: See [Does ~ always equal $HOME](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/146671)

Answer (score 3):

When a tilde (`~`) occurs unquoted, either by itself or as prefix of a username, it undergoes *tilde expansion*.  This is one of the word expansions that the shell does on *words* which is a type of grammatical token that makes up a program, and it happens before parameter expansion. A *word* is a token in the input to the shell (i.e. a script or a command from the command line) that has not been identified as a *reserved word*, such as `if` or `do`, or as an *operator* like `||` and `&&`.

This means that the tilde is not a variable, but a character that makes the shell treat the word that it is part of specially during the tilde expansion phase, under some circumstances.  This is similar to `$` in the sense that `$` marks the current word as a candidate for other types of expansions.

This is defined [by POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_01) (which also explain a bit more carefully than what I just did about when this expansion actually happens):

> 2.6.1 Tilde Expansion
>
> A "tilde-prefix" consists of an unquoted `<tilde>` character at the beginning of a word, followed by all of the characters preceding the first unquoted `<slash>` in the word, or all the characters in the word if there is no `<slash>`. In an assignment (see XBD Variable Assignment), multiple tilde-prefixes can be used: at the beginning of the word (that is, following the `<equals-sign>` of the assignment), following any unquoted `<colon>`, or both. A tilde-prefix in an assignment is terminated by the first unquoted `<colon>` or `<slash>`. If none of the characters in the tilde-prefix are quoted, the characters in the tilde-prefix following the `<tilde>` are treated as a possible login name from the user database. A portable login name cannot contain characters outside the set given in the description of the `LOGNAME` environment variable in XBD Other Environment Variables. If the login name is null (that is, the tilde-prefix contains only the tilde), the tilde-prefix is replaced by the value of the variable `HOME`. If `HOME` is unset, the results are unspecified. Otherwise, the tilde-prefix shall be replaced by a pathname of the initial working directory associated with the login name obtained using the `getpwnam()` function as defined in the System Interfaces volume of POSIX.1-2017. If the system does not recognize the login name, the results are undefined.
>
> The pathname resulting from tilde expansion shall be treated as if quoted to prevent it being altered by field splitting and pathname expansion.

Comment: You exchanged language construct for token. Still the question remains, what kind of token? It's neither a variable, nor a constant, nor an executable. Is there a type "expansion" or is it a kind of it's own?

Comment: @Blcknx I have tried to clarify the answer.  The question is akin to asking what type of thing a `$` is in the shell.

Comment: Maybe we should ask what the term "word" means in the context of a shell. They mention it with unquoted <colon>. Is "word" always a path?

Comment: In this case I would phrase the answer as this: The unquoted tilde is of type word aka path. Whenever it occurs, it is expanded to the users home directory by many shells and some other programs.

Comment: @Blcknx But that's not true. It does not expand to the user's home directory if it's quoted, and it expands to another user's home directory if it prefixes that user's username. It also does not expand if not at the beginning of a pathname. As for other programs, they may use a shell to do tilde expansion, or do their own tilde expansion, in which case it's up to the program to do it in their own special way.

Comment: @Blcknx Also, a word is not interpreted as a path by the shell unless it's given as an argument to a built-in utility and used as such. It is therefore wrong to say that the grammatical term for the tilde is a path. It would be like saying that the `$` in `$var` is a variable.

Comment: I wrote unquoted. My question is about the type of the language construct. The glory details are interesting. I think these already have been addressed in other questions.

Comment: The utilities are paths by themselves. They are relative paths to $PATH, if you don't call the by the absolute path. So this is not a contradiction, to my theses.

Comment: @Blcknx In the shell grammar, there is no such thing as a path, a utility or the variable `$PATH`.  These are not language constructs.  A language construct in the shell is a reserved word, an operator or some other word token.  Interpretation of these tokens happens later.  In this sense, the tilde is not a language construct in any other way than being a word or part of a word.

Answer (score -1):

Based on the input by @Kusalananda and @stéphane-chazelas I try to answer the question myself.

The shell is a command line interpreter. It does not strictly type the input tokens. The treatment depends on the context. There are two reasonable answers:

**Answer 1**

The tilde has no "kind of language construct" at all, because there are is no typing when the input of the shell is interpreted. Based on the context the input is treated dynamically.

**Answer 2**

The type of the tilde comes most closes to a virtual type of "path". In the typical context it is expanded to the home directory, which gives a nature similar to a variable, while it is none.

**Rationale of Answer 1**

Even flow control tokens are not typed on the Bash:

```
echo while
```

This is not an error. It just prints "while" in this context.

Depending on the context the tilde is treated differently. Typically it is expanded to the users home directory:

```
echo ~
```

In other contexts it is not expanded:

```
echo "~"
echo ~~
```

**Rationale of Answer 2**

The POSIX definition speaks of the unquoted tilde as a "word". In the normal case it is expanded to the home directory by the shell **before** being used by the shell itself as a path or before given as argument to other programs.

Used as path of an executable:

```
~/bin/myprogram
```

Used as path in an argument:

```
ls ~
```

Even expanded to the home directory before being passed as an argument, that does not need to be a path:

```
echo ~
```

Again in the typical use case, in the shell unquoted words are used as paths and quoted words as string arguments. Each call to an executable is a relative path to $PATH. Hitting  extends the words based on the paths in the file system.

** Summary **

You can use the shell in non-typical-way. For example you can use quoted strings as paths to executables:

```
"echo" echo
```

This print's echo. The typical use of quoted and unquoted is inverted.

Rationale of Answer 2 is based on conventions not on real typing. The architecture of the shell is a dynamic one.

Comment: I... can't understand half of this answer. The best I can say is that it seems you're trying to interpret the processing steps of shell commands in the context of some CS theory about languages, but not getting a really good fit, possibly because the processing steps actually don't fit the theory. That, and you're inventing stuff, like 'a virtual type of "path"' and the idea that the arguments to `echo` and `ls` would somehow differ from the shell's point of view.